# Swift 2 Iterator Extensions not working in Swift 3

Tags: swift2, iterator, swift3, extension-methods

When installing permissionScope with cocoapods, I had to convert to swift 3 syntax, most of the errors resulting from that were very simple, however I have 6 errors that involve a Sequence extension not working properly.

This is the extension from the swift 2 version:

```
extension SequenceType {
    func first(@noescape includeElement: Generator.Element -> Bool) -> Generator.Element? {
        for x in self where includeElement(x) { return x }
        return nil
    }
}
```

and swift 3

```
extension Sequence {
    func first(_ includeElement: (Iterator.Element) -> Bool) -> Iterator.Element? {
        for x in self where includeElement(x) { return x }
        return nil
    }
}
```

it is used essentially the same in swift 2 and swift 3

```
func requiredAuthorized(_ completion: @escaping (Bool) -> Void ) {
    getResultsForConfig{ (results) -> Void in
        let result = results
            .first { $0.status != .authorized }
            .isNil
        completion(result)
    }
}
```

Except in swift 3 I get an error `ambiguous use of 'first(where:)'`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In Swift 3, `Sequence` has a method `first(where:)` which behaves very similar to your extension method `first(_:)`.

(From the generated header:)

> ```
> /// Returns the first element of the sequence that satisfies the given
> /// predicate or nil if no such element is found.
> ///
> /// - Parameter predicate: A closure that takes an element of the
> ///   sequence as its argument and returns a Boolean value indicating
> ///   whether the element is a match.
> /// - Returns: The first match or `nil` if there was no match.
> public func first(where predicate: (Self.Iterator.Element) throws -> Bool) rethrows -> Self.Iterator.Element?
> ```

Remove the extension and use the `first(where:)` method in the Standard Library.